# SQL server issue - Create Function must be the only statement in the batch

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a function which I have created in SQL but I am getting this error 'SQL server issue - Create Function must be the only statement in the batch'. I checked other similar topics but couldn't find anything wrong. I am using SQL Server 2012

```
CREATE FUNCTION GETLLPATH(@objectid FLOAT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @dir VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @obj_id FLOAT;

DECLARE Name_Cursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR
SELECT A.Name, A.ParentID FROM OTCS_User.DTree A
WHERE A.DataID = @obj_id;

DECLARE 

SET @dir = NULL;
SET @obj_id = @objectid;

WHILE 1=1 BEGIN
OPEN Name_Cursor;
FETCH Name_Cursor INTO @name;
IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 BREAK or @name_NAME = 'Enterprise';
IF @dir IS NOT NULL BEGIN
SET @dir = (ISNULL(@name_NAME, '') + ':' + isnull(@dir, '')) ;
END 
IF @dir IS NULL BEGIN
SET @dir = @name_NAME;
END 
SET @obj_id = @name_PARENTID;

CLOSE Name_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE Name_Cursor;
END;

return(@dir);
END;
GO
```

I am also getting error for variables as 'Must declare Scalar variable', In the end there is one more error - 'Expecting conversation', request you to please help.

Comment: You have a rogue `DECLARE` 12 lines down

Comment: `WHILE 1=1 BEGIN` seems like a bad idea (why not `WHILE FETCH STATUS <> 0 BEGIN`?), as does a `CURSOR`, in all honesty. I suspect, however, this could very easily be turned into a dataset approach using `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF`, which you likely be a huge performance increase. A `CURSOR` in a `FUNCTION` is like asking for poor performance; as a `CURSOR` is inherently slow, and Scalar Functions are known poor performers too. A Dataset approach, and an inline-table value function would be far better.

Comment: `IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 BREAK or @name_NAME = 'Enterprise';` isn't valid syntax either, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you just have some bad code.

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GETLLPATH(
    @objectid FLOAT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @dir VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE 
        @obj_id FLOAT
        , @name_NAME VARCHAR(50) -- or whatever your field size is.
        , @name_PARENTID VARCHAR(50)    -- again, whatever your field size is.

    DECLARE Name_Cursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    SELECT A.Name, A.ParentID FROM OTCS_User.DTree A WHERE A.DataID = @obj_id;

    SET @dir = NULL; -- redundant.
    SET @obj_id = @objectid;  -- this can be set at declaration ( e.g. DELARE @obj_id FLOAT = @obj_id ).

    WHILE ( 1 = 1 ) BEGIN

        OPEN Name_Cursor;
        FETCH Name_Cursor INTO @name;

        IF ( @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 OR @name_NAME = 'Enterprise' )
            BREAK;

        IF ( @dir IS NOT NULL ) BEGIN
            SET @dir = (ISNULL(@name_NAME, '') + ':' + isnull(@dir, '')) ;
        END 

        IF @dir IS NULL BEGIN
            SET @dir = @name_NAME;
        END

        SET @obj_id = @name_PARENTID;

        CLOSE Name_Cursor;
        DEALLOCATE Name_Cursor;

    END

    RETURN @dir;

END
GO
```

On a personal note, I am **never** fond of using WHILE (1=1). Are you guaranteed to have an exit?

Also, I would highly recommend using an alternative to a cursor. Perhaps use a TABLE variable and loop through that like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GETLLPATH(
    @objectid FLOAT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN

    -- declare variables --
    DECLARE @id INT
        , @dir VARCHAR(MAX)
        , @obj_id FLOAT = @objectid
        , @name_NAME VARCHAR(50)
        , @name_PARENTID VARCHAR(50)

    -- declare table variable --
    DECLARE @data TABLE( [name] VARCHAR(50), [parent_id] VARCHAR(50), [id] INT IDENTITY (1,1) );

    -- insert data --
    INSERT INTO @data ( [name], [parent_id] )
    SELECT A.Name, A.ParentID FROM OTCS_User.DTree A WHERE A.DataID = @obj_id;

    -- for-each row... --
    SET @id = 1;
    WHILE ( @id <= ( SELECT MAX( id ) FROM @data ) )
    BEGIN

        -- current row --
        SELECT
            @name_NAME = [name]
            , @name_PARENTID = [parent_id]
        FROM @data WHERE [id] = @id;

        -- do your work here...

        -- next row --
        SET @id = ( @id + 1 );

    END

    RETURN @dir;

END
GO
```

Comment: Worked perfectly :)  Thanks for suggesting TABLE variable its a better approach

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of syntax errors even before I test your query:

1. The word 'DECLARE' should not appear in the middle without a variable name,
   @name_Name and @name_PARENTID are undeclared

   **DECLARE @name_NAME varchar, @name_PARENTID int**

(check for the variable types according to the source table)

2. IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 BREAK or @name_NAME = 'Enterprise' is incorrect

   **IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 or @name_NAME = 'Enterprise'
        BREAK**

> "Create Function must be the only statement in the batch" - usually
>   means there is some syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

This is, honestly, a total guess, and (most importantly) **completely untested**; due to the absence of sample data and expected results.

Anyway, like I said in the comments, a `CURSOR` and a Scalar-value Function are both really bad performers here. If you're trying to simply delimit your data with a colon (`:`), then you can use `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH`.

Like I said, this is completed untested, but might get you on the right path:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetllPath (@objectID int) --Is it really a float? I've used an int
RETURNS table
AS RETURN

    SELECT STUFF((SELECT ':' + DT.[Name]
                  FROM OTCS_User.DTree DT
                  WHERE DT.DataID = @obj_id
                  --ORDER BY SOMETHING HERE!!!
                  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS llPath;

GO
```